# flashcard slider plugin wordpress fix

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am using the plugin "flashcard slider" for my wordpress blog and I find it shows an extra 1 pixel wide line after every flashcard title. I found the fix but I do not know why when I upload after editing the corresponding file which defines the style, it doesn't make the change.

The slider which I am trying to edit is at the URL : http://www.digitaalcursussen.nl/gratis/grieks-belangrijkste-woorden/

The issue is explained in below figure:

[image]

Now to fix this all I need to do is change the style tags value from current style:

```
style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; z-index: 3; opacity: 1; padding-right: 25px;"
```

to

```
style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0.5px; display: block; z-index: 3; opacity: 1; padding-right: 25px;"
```

You may check this on website. In the php file of plugin, code which defines the style was edited like this:

```
$html .='<div class="flashcard_front flashcard_side" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0.5px;  display: block; z-index: 3; opacity: 1; padding-right:25px">
                    '.$title_up_html
                    .$slider_content_front
                    .$toback_control.
                '</div>
```

but I do not know why after uploading the php file, the attribute left: 0.5px reverts to left: 0px

What is the reason? I have spent hours on this so please help me.

As far as write permissions and all are confirmed, yes I am able to edit some other attribute like padding-right:35 px, I have tried that and it changed on website as well after upload but I don't know for what reason the left:0px is not changing at all?